# Redirect to ItemID using windows.location.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it a possible using `windows.location.replace` to redirect to ItemID. 
Like, I have one `input text` and `button` and when user input like `123` and if this item exist in database it need to redirect to this item.

```
$.ajax({          
            type: "GET",            
            URL: "/api/Akontas/GetAKONTA",
            data: { id: $('#AkontasId').val() },
            contentType: "data/xml; charset=utf-8",  
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.replace("http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId'));
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }
        });
```

Something like this if exsist return xml data
[image]

Otherwise return `No data found with this ID`

[image]

**Update**

[image]

[image]

Comment: on redirect you forgot `val()` so use `$('#AkontasId').val()`

Comment: try `window.location.href` instead of `.replace`, this question will probably get closed I am afraid as it has been asked hundreds of times before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie You didnt get point. I want to redirect base on input ID 
Is it possible in windows.location.href pass ID

Comment: explain further? redirect base what?

Comment: to pass the ID you can just concat the string - so you would build the URL as `'http://url.com/' + yourVar`

Comment: see what Devsi wrote, he has pointed you to why it isn't working, I was trying to answer the 'is it possible' part of your question.

Comment: Look at last two picture and you will se what I need

Comment: Sorry bud I must be being thick...it looks like you are asking how to redirect to the page with a certain ID, Devsi gave you the answer why your code isn't redirecting and I gave you how to build the strings and a general answer, what isn't working if you do as Devsi suggests and change `window.location.replace("http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId'));` with `window.location.href("http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId').val());`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line from this:

```
window.location.replace("http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId'));
```

to this:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId').val();
```